# how to make input async (python)

Tags: python, windows, asynchronous, input, terminal

I need to make output and input work at the same time.
Already tried to make it several times, watched like 10 the same posts but they don't solve my problem at all.

[tried solving by using prompt_toolkit library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ6ck.png)
more solutions i tried to use:
[Python async: Waiting for stdin input while doing other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454190/python-async-waiting-for-stdin-input-while-doing-other-stuff)
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/oqn18z/comment/h6cnpti/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

I saw people saying that better creating gui than terminal interface, but I need to make commands and don't know how to make terminal gui in like pyqt, and I think my stuff looks better in console than gui.

Also, i saw this post [Problem with ainput (Async input in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72351945/problem-with-ainput-async-input-in-python) in category "Review questions already on Stack Overflow to see if your question is a duplicate" and saw something in it, but I don't see how to use it properly or if its any helpful.

Example code:

```
user = User("...")
 
@user.on.message(text="ping")
async def messagehandler(msg: Message):
    msg.answer("pong")
 
async def main():
    while True:
        command = input(Style.RESET_ALL + " > ")
        await HandleCommand(command)
 
user.loop.run_until_complete(main())
user.run_forever()
```

Comment: what is your code?  do you need to accept user input, or piped via stdin? what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i have a console with commands and a event handler (like discord.py on message handler) and the handler doesn't work while console does "while true input"

Comment: forgot, code example: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/h13f7Swh)

Comment: please put code in the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `ainput` from `aioconsole` library does sound like probably what you need

Comment: ainput literally does nothing, if i replace input with ainput nothing changes, it's probably because while true

Comment: show your code using `ainput` (do you `command = await ainput(...)` ?)

Comment: just change input to ainput brother ...

Comment: you need to `await` it for the async-ness to work

Comment: you know, it will error if dont await it, so it useless to tell me it. I already said 2 times its because while true.